# Why not have iCloud keychain as default?

Tags: ios, icloud, macos, password, keychain

Yosemite 10.10.1 and iOS 8.1.2

On my Keychain Access on OS X, I have the "login" default keychain and an "iCloud" keychain (I have iCloud Keychain ON for all my devices).

I'm just wondering, could I just copy all items from "login" to "iCloud" keychain, in order to have it available on my iOS just in case? If that is the case, why wouldn't this be the default behaviour when I "save a password" on my Mac?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Within `Keychain Access` the 'login' keychain is the user names and passwords that you have stored for the current logged in user. The `iCloud` keychain is as the title states stored in the cloud available to be accessed on any devices under the same `Apple ID`.

The main risk with storing anything within a cloud service is the risk of these online services being hacked. `OS/X` devices are multi user environments, and under these setups often share an `iCloud` account, or are using `iCloud Family Sharing` feature. These features could lead to passwords being available to users/family that you would not want to have access to.

As for copying the items over, as far as I am aware there is no way of doing this, looking within `Keychain Access` application there is no option for this. Also within preferences there is no option to set the default location, any new passwords will be stored within the 'login' keychain.

Hopefully this has cleared things up for you.

Comment: Family sharing (the feature Apple offers, not the act of sharing your Apple ID logged into iCloud with your family) does not share your keychain. The rest of your answer stands true.

Answer (score 0):

Copying or moving items is trivial. Either copy them (e.g. edit menu) or drag them. You will need to confirm the action for each item with your password.